# Computing Feynman propagator with momentum-dependent form factor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, fermions, integration, propagator

Can anyone help me to solve the following problem? I want to compute the integral

\begin{equation}\label{eq:q0}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dq_0 \, \frac{f(q^2)\,\exp[-i q_0(t_1-t_2)]}{[q_0-(|\vec{q}|-i\varepsilon)][q_0-(-|\vec{q}|+i\varepsilon)]} \,,
\end{equation}

i.e., a massless fermion [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) with a momentum-dependent [form factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_factor_(quantum_field_theory))

\begin{equation}
f(q^2)=\frac{1}{1+\exp[2(q_0^2-|\vec{q}|^2-\Lambda^2)/\Lambda^2]}\,,
\end{equation}

where $\Lambda$ is some energy scale, $\Lambda^2 \ll \langle q_0^2\rangle \sim \langle |\vec{q}|^2 \rangle$.

Without the form factor, the standard procedure for evaluating such a [Feynman propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Feynman_propagator) would be to make a [contour integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration) over the complex plane, where the contour $C$ goes along the real axis from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and then along a semicircle centered at $0$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ (clockwise for $t_1-t_2>0$ and counterclockwise for $t_1-t_2<0$). According to the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), the result of the integral would correspond to the residues at $q_0= \pm |\vec{q}|\mp i\varepsilon$.

However, the form factor now makes the problem more complicated. It has singularities at $q_0= \pm\sqrt{(2 b^2 + i π + 2 i n π)/2}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. If we approximate it as $f(q^2)\approx \exp[-2(q_0^2-|\vec{q}|^2-\Lambda^2)/\Lambda^2]$ due to $\Lambda^2 \ll \langle q_0^2\rangle \sim \langle |\vec{q}|^2 \rangle$, it has essential singularities on the imaginary axis for $q_0^2\rightarrow-\infty$.

How do I perform a contour integration, which involves poles both on the real axis and essential singularities at infinity on the imaginary axis? Can I simply apply the residue theorem for the poles at $q_0= \pm |\vec{q}|\mp i\varepsilon$ and ignore the singularities of the exponential function? In this case, the integration would simply yield the result $\exp[\mp i |\vec{q}|(t_1-t_2)]/(\pm 2|\vec{q}|)$. But shouldn't also the exponential function and its singularities affect the result of the integration? Is the integral over the arc not convergent, which could be cured by choosing a different contour, e.g., a rectangular one?